# can I use a constructor to initialize any number of elements, in a class with a template that takes 1 and an associated structure?

Tags: c++

i have such a class

```
template <typename T>
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<pointNode> next;

        pointNode():data(std::move(T{})),next(std::move(std::unique_ptr<pointNode>{})){}
        pointNode(T n_data, std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr) : data(std::move(n_data)), next(std::move(ptr)) {}

        
    };
    std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head;
public:
    
    Store() : head(std::unique_ptr<pointNode>{}) {}
    Store(const T& data);
    Storek(const T& data, std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr);
};
```

I haven't worked with creating a unique_ptr and any number of elements yet, so I can't understand whether it is possible, in principle, to create a constructor with such a class that would handle such a call:

```
Store<int> temp{1,2,3,5};
```

I tried to do something with std:: initializer_list.

```
Store(initializer_list<T> args);
```

But I can't think of a way to link this to unique_ptr and make it create such a list.
Maybe in my case it is impossible to do this at all?I would be happy to answer ,thank you

Comment: You could use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in a hacky two-liner:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<pointNode> tail;

        pointNode(T n_data, std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr) : 
            data(std::move(n_data)), tail(std::move(ptr)) {}

    };
    std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head;
public:
    
    Store() : head(std::unique_ptr<pointNode>{}) {}

    template<typename...Args>
    Store(Args&&...args){
        int tmp=0;
        // compound assignments are the only right-asociative operators
        
        (tmp+=...+=(head = std::make_unique<pointNode>(std::forward<Args>(args),std::move(head)),0));
        // Comma would built reversed list.
        // ((head = std::make_unique<pointNode>(std::forward<Args>(args),std::move(head))),...);

    }    

    
    void print()const {
        for(auto ptr=head.get();ptr;ptr=ptr->tail.get()){
            std::cout<<ptr->data<<' ';
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Store<int> s{1,2,3,4,5};
    s.print();
}
```

Output([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fx6aba)):

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Wow.Thank you very much.And if it is not difficult for you, then you could explain this line ,I, frankly, see this for the first time.

(tmp+=...+=(head = std::make_unique<pointNode>(std::forward<Args>(args),std::move(head)),0));

I can't understand what's going on here,we assign head to the right ,but we also move it to the left side.I also did not see such a trick with tmp :)